# Are selector IDs sensitive to argument types?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

When you retrieve the ID of a selector with `@selector()`, is the selector value different depending on the types of the arguments?

Here's what I mean. I have a method that takes an object reference and a selector, then calls it with a parameter:

```
-(void)CallLater:(NSObject*) Obj Sel: (SEL)Sel
{
    //Some stuff, then:
    [Obj performSelector: Sel withObject: SomeOtherObject];
}
```

I'm using this method with a selector to a function that takes a typed object reference, not an `id`:

```
-(void)MyMethod: (MyObject*) a
{
}

[self CallLater: self Sel:@selector(MyMethod:)];
```

It seems to work, but my senses are tingling. In a statically typed language like C# this would be a foul, an upcast - `CallLater` is expecting a selector for a function that takes an `id` and I'm giving it a function that takes a `MyObject`.

On the other hand, the compiler does not complain, and both `id` and concrete object references seems to be mere pointers deep down, trivially castable to one another. Then again, there are many fouls that Objective C compiler does not complain about.

So the real question is - is it safe? Language lawyers welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's safe; objects are objects. A selector parameter for an `NSObject *` is exactly the same as a selector parameter for a `MyObject *`.

If you want MyMethod to verify that it's being called with an object of a particular type, it should do a NSParameterAssert on it:

```
NSParameterAssert([obj isKindOfClass: [MyObject class]]);
```

Personally, I rarely do this check. It's enough that the actual object *acts* like the type I want it to be, and if it doesn't I'll get a runtime error (usually unrecognized selector). You'll get a compiler warning in the simple cases, and it's worth paying attention to this warning (and silencing it with an id cast when necessary).

I'm a  bit confused here about your use of `id` in your question, so I want to make sure you understand this: An `NSObject *` is exactly as much an `id` as a `MyObject *` is. `id` is a generic instance pointer class, whereas `NSObject *` is a `NSObject` instance (or a subclass of `NSObject`). You can have objects that don't descend from `NSObject`. But you're unlikely to ever have to know this.

Other notes, re: convention:

- Selectors (both the name and parameters) start with lowercase letters, so `CallLater:Sel:` should be `callLater:sel:`.
- Variable and parameter names start with lowercase letters; `Obj` above should be `obj`.
- Class names do start with an uppercase letter. :)

Comment: By "is expecting a function" I mean the second parameter.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. But you said it takes an id, and you talk about id elsewhere. But nowhere in your code is there an id. I assume you're talking about id in the general "instance" sense, but I thought I should point out that NSObject is no more an id than MyObject.

Comment: Also, convention is that your method should be called `callLater:sel:" rather than "CallLater:Sel:" (etc, etc: camel case for selectors leads with lowercase).

Comment: I'm not confused on the difference between `id` and `NSObject*`. But the whole technique has a whiff of "let's just cast it to `void*`" to it. Neither C# delegates nor C++ pointers-to-members work this way.

Comment: Yes, you're quite right. I mean no offense by this (because I suffered from this for a long time, too) but this is counter-language thinking. It's enough that an object *acts like* the object type you expect, rather than actually *is* the object type you expect. I've tried to clarify this a bit by expanding on how to check the type, and why you probably don't need to. :)

Comment: Edited the question slightly: "CallLater is expecting *a selector* for a function that takes an id and I'm giving it a function that takes a MyObject". Hope now the source of my confusion is more clear, for posterity's sake.